# Can an addon communicate with downthemall addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

**Hi,**
I want to write firefox addon for managing 
download links (scheduling , retrying, auto refresh download address ...)

but I don't want to reinvent the wheel (It won't actually download it will just managing the links as above)

so ,
Is there a way to communicate with downThemall (or - if not possible - firefox regular download) ? Is there some api or something to communicate with another addon ?

- Add links to the DTA
- get link status (complete ,paused ,failed)
- ... whatever else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an [API](https://github.com/downthemall/downthemall-mirror/blob/master/modules/api.js). It is exposed to ChromeWindow through the `DTA` global variable.

Comment: Hello, how to add that API to my website? and use the code similar to here: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2709131